# Is there something wrong and i get 0 as value from Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I m trying to take a value from firebase, and always i get "0". I check my code and i cant find any error.

I used the same code in another activity and i had the correct value. Now for no reason as i didnt made any change, in both activities i cant read the value that i need

Json file:

```
"Ranking" : {
"Aditi" : {
  "avatarUrl" : "https://i.imgur.com/S9dkvBA.png",
  "score" : 60,
  "userClass" : "Wizard",
  "userName" : "Aditi"
   },
```

And my code:

```
//Method to get the userScore from Ranking table in firebase
public void getScore() {
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String name = user.getDisplayName();
    DatabaseReference rankingScore;
    rankingScore = database.getReference("Ranking");

    rankingScore.orderByChild("userName").equalTo(name)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Ranking ranking = data.getValue(Ranking.class);
                        totalScore = ranking.getScore();
                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
}
```

I expect the value of "60" but i get "0"

Update: Ranking class

public class Ranking {

```
private String userName;
private long score;
private String avatarUrl;
private String userClass;

public Ranking(String userName, long score, String avatarUrl, String userClass) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.score = score;
    this.avatarUrl = avatarUrl;
    this.userClass = userClass;
}

public Ranking() {

}

public Ranking(String userName, long score) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.score = score;
}

public Ranking(String userName, long score, String avatarUrl) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.score = score;
    this.avatarUrl = avatarUrl;
}




public String getUserClass() {
    return userClass;
}

public void setUserClass(String userClass) {
    this.userClass = userClass;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public long getScore() {
    return score;
}

public void setScore(long score) {
    this.score = score;
}

public String getAvatarUrl() {
    return avatarUrl;
}

public void setAvatarUrl(String avatarUrl) {
    this.avatarUrl = avatarUrl;
}
```

}

Comment: Where are you checking the the value of `totalScore`? Because I cannot see any log statement for that. Please also add a screenshot of your database.

Comment: Can you also post your Ranking class ?

Comment: @AlexMamo i have in my onCreate: getScore();
        String totalScoreText = String.valueOf(totalScore);
        Toast.makeText(GameChooseActivity.this,
                totalScoreText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); just to check the value

Comment: @HealthydevDevelopments If you try to use `Toast.makeText(GameChooseActivity.this, totalScoreText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` inside the `onDataChange()` method, does it work correctly?

Comment: Also check your database rules and make sure you have the permission to read the data on the app side

Comment: Maybe nothing but, you expected String "60"? but  `ranking.getScore()` return Long

Comment: @Erik It doesnt matter at the moment as i make it String for the check.

Comment: @kidrocker The code is in a full working application. I can read all the firebase database and actually in another activity i read all the Ranking with no problem

Comment: Uninstal app and reinstall, sometimes the Firebase offline(if you have it turned on) cache can play tricks on you during dev

Comment: @Alex Mamo Hmmm i tried your "trick" and i got the right value, so i guess the problem is not at the firebase reading value, but with the variable.

Comment: So it did the trick. This is beacause Firebase API's are asynchronous. Please check the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

just add child("Aditi") in reference :-

```
public void getScore() {
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String name = user.getDisplayName();
    DatabaseReference rankingScore;
    rankingScore = database.getReference("Ranking").child("Aditi");

    rankingScore.orderByChild("userName").equalTo(name)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Ranking ranking = data.getValue(Ranking.class);
                        totalScore = ranking.getScore();
                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
}
```

Comment: "Aditi" is the user name, i dont want to get the score from specific player but from Firabse current user.  rankingScore.orderByChild("userName").equalTo(name) supposed to do this